# artwork of current playing song using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer, want to know "How to display the artwork(Image if any)" of current playing song(audio) in MAC os x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-[AVAudioPlayer url]` will give you the url of the file being played.

Passing that to `+[AVURLAsset assetWithURL:]` will give you an `AVURLAsset` object representing the track being played. Calling `-[AVAsset commonMetadata]` will get you an array of `AVMetadataItem`s. You can pass that array to `+[AVMetadataItem metadataItemsFromArray:withKey:keySpace:]` with the `AVMetadataCommonKeyArtwork` key to get the proper `AVMetadataItem` corresponding to the artwork.

Relevant documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAsset
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVURLAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVURLAsset
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVMetadataItem

Good luck!